# ¿Como Conectar mas de un QPushButton con un solo metodo?

Tags: python, pyside

al realizar una lista de QPushButton como puedo saber quien realizo clic de toda la lista de los botones y enviárselo a un método que comparten todos los pushbuton.
intente con `self.sender` y el resultado de eso es None.

```
self.ListaDeButons.insert(self.i,QPushButton(boton))
self.ListaDeButons[self.i].setObjectName("Boton_"+str(self.i))
self.ListaDeButons[self.i].setGeometry(QRect((315*self.contadorX)+115,self.contadorY+280,150,35))
self.ListaDeButons[self.i].setVisible(True)
self.ListaDeButons[self.i].clicked.connect(lambda:print(self.sender()))
```

Comment: Cada vez que conectes una función a la señal clicked, usa un [partial](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial). Y pasa de argumento al partial el boton.

Comment: No entendi como hacerlo

Comment: Algo como button.clicked.connect(partial(mifuncion, button)). De esa forma, se pasa automaticamente el argumento button a la función mifuncion (luego de pasar los argumentos que el partial recibe)

Comment: Perdon soy nuevo gracias XD

Comment: No me molestaste, tanquilo c: